# How to set the CPU to do alignment checking

Tags: memory-alignment, elevated-privileges

I want to be able to set the CPU (x86) to do alignment checking in order to verify that on my code there are no misaligned data references. I know that ultimately I need to set the AC flag in the EFLAGS register and the AM flag in CR0 register, that the AC flag can easily be set with the pushfd / popfd instructions, and that the AM flag can be set with a mov to and from CR0 instruction. However, that last instruction can only be executed in privileged mode.

Short of writing a kernel-mode driver, is there any way to enter privileged mode?

More generally, how could I set the CPU to do alignment checking?